# Classify values based on datetime criteria

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, datetime-format, data-wrangling

I want to be able to classify some events in R based on datetime criteria. I have two data sets the first one has the datetime and id of customer that have called a hotels corporate telephone line, and the other dataset has the datetime and customer id of all booking reservations for the same hotel.

Corporate line:

```
CTEL <- tibble::tribble(
 ~ID,  ~DATE_CALL,
 "01",  "08-25-20021 18:21:28",
 "01",  "07-26-20021 18:11:06",
 "02", "09-26-20021 18:21:01",
 "02",  "10-27-20021 20:21:59",
 "03",   "08-20-20021 20:21:02",
 "03",   "09-30-20021 20:21:03",
 "04",  "09-29-20021 20:21:04",
 "05",  "05-25-20021 20:21:05"
)
```

Bookings:

```
BOOKINGS <- tibble::tribble(
 ~ID,        ~BOOKINGS,         ~DATE_OF_BOOKING,       
 "01",   "UI89D", "08-20-20021 18:21:28", 
 "02", "PL882", "07-29-20021 18:11:06",
 "03",   "1254SDD", "01-27-20021 20:21:02", 
 "03", "DODK5845", "11-20-20021 20:21:03",
 "03", "MHXVJ7854E", "08-29-20021 20:21:02", 
 "04",   "85IORZ", "09-30-20021 20:21:04", 
 "05", "ZUI89DM", "8-25-20021 21:21:05", 
)
```

I want to be able to create three new variables. One of them is PRIOR? with two values "YES" and "NO" and the other one is called AFTER? with two values "YES" and "ONE" as well. The final one is the number of reservation  RESERV_NUM

Classification rules: **PRIOR?**

If a customer makes a reservation *A* with datetime *X* I want to know if this person has called on the line within the last 30 days prior to this reservation *A*, if that turns out to be true then let PRIOR? be "YES" otherwise "NO"

Classification rules: **AFTER?**

If a customer makes a reservation *A* with datetime *X* I want to know if this person has called on the line within the next 3 days after this reservation *A*, if that turns out to be true then let AFTER? be "YES" otherwise "NO"

Classification rules: **RESERV_NUM**

If a customer makes a reservation *A* and then makes a reservation *B* and after that they make a reservation *C* I want to be able to assign by customer's reservation if the reservation "*x*" is their first, second, third, and so on... To illustrate this would be:

| ID | BOOKINGS | RESERV_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1 |
| 001 | B | 2 |
| 001 | C | 3 |

**Example of desired output**

An example of the desired output for ID:003 would be:

| ID | BOOKINGS | RESERV_NUM | PRIOR? | AFTER? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1254SDD | 1 | NO | NO |
| 001 | DODK5845 | 3 | NO | NO |
| 001 | MHXVJ7854E | 2 | YES | NO |

This is correct because for the date of the reservation MHXVJ7854E , we have a record of a call 30 days before the date of such reservation and also no call record within the next 3 days after that reservation.

**What Have I tried?**

The key to this problem is to identify to extract the date of each reservation and then extract the latest record on the telephone line prior to the reservation date and also the latest record on the line 3 days after the reservation date.

So I started by first joining the two datasets and sorting in dates in chronological order by booking and date of call and I can easily pick the latest date of reservation and the latest date for call but, I am lost when it comes to selecting these days knowing that the "reference" should be the date of the reservation maybe I can explain my quest with this illustration:

```
<-------------------------- Booking/Reservation_Date--------------------->
        30 days after                                     3 days later
```

In order to solve the issue I created two different datasets one with a filter so that all datetimes in the record of the telephone line are less than the reservation date and then I select the latest one..and the other dataset will have the records of calls after each reservation by booking reservation... I will later one select the latest call and compare if it is within the "next 3 days after the reservation".. then I will have to join again the two datasets... but this process although it gives the correct results it can be a bit messy and lengthy.. I dont know if you talented , brilliant people can guide me to use a more refine solution.

the other thing is that I have no idea as to how to assign the RESERV_NUM to each BOOKING.. is there a function on R that can do that?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `RESERV_NUM`, as the customer can call on today to make a reservation on next month and call on tomorrow to make a reservation on this month, I simply ordered the `RESERV_NUM` by the `DATE_OF_BOOKING` in `BOOKINGS`.

```
# I have convert the date to 2021 rather than 20021, which will cause error.
CTEL <- tibble::tribble(
   ~ID,  ~DATE_CALL,
   "01",  "08-25-2021 18:21:28",
   "01",  "07-26-2021 18:11:06",
   "02", "09-26-2021 18:21:01",
   "02",  "10-27-2021 20:21:59",
   "03",   "08-20-2021 20:21:02",
   "03",   "09-30-2021 20:21:03",
   "04",  "09-29-2021 20:21:04",
   "05",  "05-25-2021 20:21:05"
 )
 
 BOOKINGS <- tibble::tribble(
   ~ID,        ~BOOKINGS,         ~DATE_OF_BOOKING,       
   "01",   "UI89D", "08-20-2021 18:21:28", 
   "02", "PL882", "07-29-2021 18:11:06",
   "03",   "1254SDD", "01-27-2021 20:21:02", 
   "03", "DODK5845", "11-20-2021 20:21:03",
   "03", "MHXVJ7854E", "08-29-2021 20:21:02", 
   "04",   "85IORZ", "09-30-2021 20:21:04", 
   "05", "ZUI89DM", "08-25-2021 21:21:05", 
 ) 
 
 
 lapply(unique(BOOKINGS$ID), function(x){
   bookings <- dplyr::filter(BOOKINGS, ID == x)
   ctel <- dplyr::filter(CTEL, ID == x)
   
   bookings$DATE_OF_BOOKING <- strptime(bookings$DATE_OF_BOOKING, format = "%m-%d-%Y %T")
   ctel$DATE_CALL <- strptime(ctel$DATE_CALL, format = "%m-%d-%Y %T")
   pa <- plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(bookings$DATE_OF_BOOKING, function(y){
     cond <- sum(ctel$DATE_CALL <= y & ctel$DATE_CALL >= y - lubridate::ddays(30)) > 0
     prior <- ifelse(cond, "YES", "NO")
     cond <- sum(ctel$DATE_CALL >= y & ctel$DATE_CALL <= y + lubridate::ddays(3)) > 0
     after <- ifelse(cond, "YES", "NO")
     return(as.data.frame(list(prior = prior, after = after)))
   }))
   
   output <- cbind(bookings, pa)
   output <- output[order(output$DATE_OF_BOOKING), ]
   output$RESERV_NUM <- c(1:nrow(output))
   output <- output[, c("ID", "BOOKINGS", "RESERV_NUM", "prior", "after")]
   names(output) <- c("ID", "BOOKINGS", "RESERV_NUM", "PRIOR?", "AFTER?")
   rownames(output) <- NULL
   
   return(output)
 })

## [[1]]
##   ID BOOKINGS RESERV_NUM PRIOR? AFTER?
## 1 01    UI89D          1    YES     NO
##
## [[2]]
##   ID BOOKINGS RESERV_NUM PRIOR? AFTER?
## 1 02    PL882          1     NO     NO
##
## [[3]]
##   ID   BOOKINGS RESERV_NUM PRIOR? AFTER?
## 1 03    1254SDD          1     NO     NO
## 2 03 MHXVJ7854E          2    YES     NO    # Notice that customer 3 did not call back within three days
## 3 03   DODK5845          3     NO     NO
##
## [[4]]
##  ID BOOKINGS RESERV_NUM PRIOR? AFTER?
## 1 04   85IORZ          1    YES     NO
##
## [[5]]
##  ID BOOKINGS RESERV_NUM PRIOR? AFTER?
## 1 05  ZUI89DM          1     NO     NO
```

Comment: hey thank you so much for your answer this is quite a lovely way to result my inquiry and I am very thankful for that I also have to study your code since I am not familiar with the l apply function, I have a final question is there a way to retrieve the answer as a table format for the final output? I noticed that it has a format that is not of a table for also not of a matrix so I am a little bit confused (not your fault) please know that I am just an R student so I am also learning. You did amazing 10/10